# Is it safe to `std::move(*this)` into an object being created from `this->some_method`?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to build a chain of callable objects that can be later executed asynchronously. I wanted to try out the following approach: build a "nested" structure of nodes *(by moving each node into its "parent")* resulting in an object that stores all the computations and can be start the chain on demand.

This is what I had in mind:

```
template <typename TParent, typename TF>
struct node
{
    TParent _parent;
    TF _f;

    node(TParent&& parent, TF&& f) 
        : _parent{std::move(parent)}, _f{std::move(f)}
    {
    }

    template <typename TFContinuation>
    auto then(TFContinuation&& f_continuation)
    {
        using this_type = node<TParent, TF>;
        return node<this_type, std::decay_t<TFContinuation>>
            {std::move(*this), std::move(f_continuation)};
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//           ...safe?
    }   
};
```

The code above would allow the user to write chains like the following one:

```
int main()
{
    node n{some_root_callable, []{/*...*/}};
    n.then([]{/*...*/})
     .then([]{/*...*/})
     .then([]{/*...*/})
     .then([]{/*...*/});
}
```

*(The real implementation would support more useful abstraction such as `when_all(...)` or `when_any(...)`.)*

[**Wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RAkwSTT98CoBseS9).

---

Assuming that `TParent`, `TF`, and `TFContinuation` are movable callable objects, **is it safe *(i.e. well-defined)* to call `std::move(*this)` during the invocation of `node::then`?**

Comment: it really depends on how are you going to use `*this` after the move. if you don't break anything (aka, leaving the state of the object in a state that the destructor cannot handle) I can't see a problem.

Comment: `std::move` does not move anything, so what you can do after the _move_ mostly depends on what the constructor of `TParent` actually does. That said, you can delete the `this` pointer and still get away with it. As long as you don't play with what remains after the _move_, I don't see any reason for which you can't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that and it's safe. It will only leaves members in an *undefined but valid state* in *most cases*. With that said, it is safe to move `this`, as long as you don't try to use its members again. But with standard library types and most user defined types, this won't even be a problem.

There is one thing that I would change. I would only allow call from rvalue this:

```
template <typename TFContinuation> //      v-- notice the && here.
auto then(TFContinuation&& f_continuation) && {
    using this_type = node<TParent, TF>;

    return node<this_type, std::decay_t<TFContinuation>>{
        std::move(*this), std::move(f_continuation)
    };
}
```

The great this is you can even overload it when it's not an rvalue:

```
template <typename TFContinuation>
auto then(TFContinuation&& f_continuation) const & {
    using this_type = node<TParent, TF>;

    return node<this_type, std::decay_t<TFContinuation>>{
        *this, std::move(f_continuation)
    };
}
```

Comment: Re: "leaves members in an undefined but valid state" -- that's true for all types **defined in the standard library** (that's where those words come from), but there is no guarantee that user-defined types will do this. So "it's safe" is too strong a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there's a problem in that code depends on what that code does with the reference that it gets. If the called code turns the object into mush, then when it returns, your code has to deal with an object that's been turned into mush. But that's true of **any** function that you call from a member function, regardless of whether its called with an rvalue reference, a modifiable lvalue reference, a pointer, or any other mechanism you might want to imagine.

Comment: The rvalue-ref returned from `std::move(*this)` is passed as the `parent` parameter of the newly-constructed `node` object, in order to store the "parent node" inside the new node's `_parent` field. The idea is to recursively store nodes of the asynchronous computation into each other, in order to build a "big" object that contains all the data required to later start executing the asynchronous chain.

Comment: After that, the hierarchy is traversed and the asynchronous computation is built by recursively calling an `execute()` method on all stored objects. I have [a non-working implementation](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HfrjVkob1QP476QT) here, which segfaults on g++ *(but not on clang++)*. I've been trying to understand where the UB is for a while, and `std::move(*this)` looked like a "red flag".